# Was bedeutet dieses komische „meinetwegen“?

Tags: single-word-request

Ich würde gerne haargenau verstehen, was *meinetwegen* in folgendem Kontext heißt:

> Die Fahrt dauert ca. zwei Stunden. Oder **meinetwegen** anderthalb.

Was meint der Sprecher damit? Meine Vermutung lautet, dass *meinetwegen* irgendwie durch *sogar* ersetzt werden kann. Als ob der Sprecher betonen wollte, dass „die Fahrt nicht so lang wäre“.

Ich bin fast sicher, dass dieser Satz keinem der folgenden aus [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/meinetwegen) stammenden Bedeutungen passt (eventuell der lezte *3a*).

> Bedeutungen:
>
> 1. bezieht den Grund auf die erste Person Singular: aus einem mich betreffenden Grunde
> 2. um mir gut zu tun, für mich
> 3. umgangssprachlich, drückt das Einverständnis, die Erlaubnis zu einer Aktion aus (ohne jene zu bekräftigen): weil ich es erlaube, nichts dagegen habe
>    3a. oft als Interjektion

Comment: Ist durch 3. abgedeckt, allerdings weniger Erlaubnis, als Kompromissbereitschaft bei einer abweichenden Behauptung. Man antizipiert einen anderen Schätzer, der mutiger oder vorsichtiger ist und diesem signalisiert man Einverständnis, unabhängig von der realen Existenz einer zweiten Person mit solch einer Meinung.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im Duden werden drei Bedeutungen von *meinetwegen* unterschieden (die ausgewählten Beispiele stammen aus verschiedenen Bänden):

> **1.** *aus Gründen, die mich betreffen; mir zuliebe; um meinetwillen:*
> bist du meinetwegen gekommen?
> meinetwegen brauchst du nicht zu warten
> sie taten dies alles meinetwegen
> bemühe dich meinetwegen nicht
> du hast meinetwegen ja auch auf mancherlei verzichtet
>
> **2.** (ugs.) *von mir aus:*
> meinetwegen kannst du gehen
> meinetwegen! (ich habe nichts dagegen!)
>
> **3.** *zum Beispiel; angenommen:*
> nehmen wir eine Zahl, meinetwegen vier, und …
> zunächst absolvierst du ein Studium, meinetwegen Veterinärmedizin
> Wenn man früh genug anfängt, mit sechzehn meinetwegen
> Ich kannte einen Mann … Der ging samstags … schwarzarbeiten, verdiente meinetwegen 200 Mark

(Die dritte Bedeutung aus dem Duden fehlt in [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/meinetwegen).)

Dementsprechend werden in Duden – *Das Synonymwörterbuch* je nach Bedeutung ganz unterschiedliche Synonyme aufgeführt:

> **1.** für mich, mir zuliebe, mit Rücksicht auf mich, um meinetwillen; *(ugs.):* wegen mir; *(landsch., sonst veraltet):* wegen meiner.
>
> **2.** einverstanden, es soll mir recht sein, gut, ich habe nichts dagegen/keine Einwände, in Ordnung, ja, nun gut/schön, ruhig, wenn es denn sein muss, wie du meinst/willst; *(ugs.):* in Gottes Namen, okay, von mir aus, wegen mir; *(ugs. abwertend):* soll er/sie doch; *(veraltend):* meinethalben.
>
> **3.** angenommen, beispielshalber, beispielsweise, etwa, zum Beispiel; *(bildungsspr.):* exempli causa; *(veraltend):* zum Exempel.

Je nach Kontext könnte es sich bei der Verwendung

> Die Fahrt dauert ca. zwei Stunden. Oder **meinetwegen** anderthalb.

aus der Frage entweder um ein willkürlich angenommenes Beispiel (3. Bedeutung)

> Die Fahrt dauert gewöhnlich ungefähr zwei Stunden. **Angenommen,** sie dauert nur anderthalb Stunden, dann …

oder um ein Zugeständnis (2. Bedeutung)

> „Die Fahrt dauert höchstens eine Stunde.“ – „Nein, die Fahrt dauert ungefähr zwei Stunden; **von mir aus** dauert sie nur anderthalb Stunden, aber auf jeden Fall dauert sie länger als eine Stunde.“

handeln.

Answer (score 8):

"meinetwegen" wird gerne von Eltern verwendet:

> Mama, darf ich einen Keks haben? Meinetwegen.

Das heißt dann: Ja, Du gibst ansonsten ja doch keine Ruhe, ist also mehr eine Kapitulation als eine Zustimmung. Man lernt es als Kind recht schnell ;-).

Bei den unterschiedlichen Zeitangaben ist es als präventives Eingeständnis zu verstehen, dass die Fahrzeit abweichen kann, um nicht nachher dem Vorwurf ausgesetzt zu sein, dass die Fahrt doch nur anderthalb Stunden gedauert habe. Insofern würde ich es als Modalpartikel ansehen.

Comment: +1 für `präventives Eingeständnis`. Es ist also die 3. Bedeutung, um einem erwarteten Widerspruch vorweg zuzustimmen.

Comment: Ich würde 'Meinetwegen' viel simpler, als wiederwillige Zustimmung interpretieren. Es ist relativ universell einsetzbar, wie die 3. Bedeutungen (Beispiele) aufzeigen. Es hat keinen eindeutigen Anwendungsfall. Mehr ein synonem für "Von mir aus".

Comment: Ich würde statt "Eingeständnis" eher "Zugeständnis" schreiben, was auch dem hier vermuteten Feilschen um die tatsächliche Fahrtdauer entspricht.

Comment: "Meinetwegen" kann sowohl beim Keks-Beispiel als auch im OP-Beispiel von mir aus durch "Wenn du unbedingt darauf bestehst" ersetzt werden.

Answer (score 0):

"meinetwegen" als Reaktion auf eine Bitte oder einen Vorschlag drückt Einverständnis aus, aber man ist nicht geradezu begeistert. Man ringt sich mehr oder weniger zu einem Einverständnis durch. 
Eine andere Sache ist es zu erklären, wie dieses Wort zu einer Formel für Einverständnis werden kann. Aber diese Frage kommt mir erst jetzt, während ich das hier schreibe. Ud ich glaube, eine solche Erklärung ist gar nicht so einfach. Aus dem Stegreif kann ich dazu nichts sagen.